# Annotation on member and Aspectj

Tags: java, annotations, aspectj

I would like to be able to annotate a member of my class and then set up Around pointcuts which trigger on its get and set methods.  Rough example:

```
public class Point {
   @Monitor
   private int x;

   public int getX() { return x;}
   public void setX(int v) {x = v; }
}
```

```
@Aspect
public class MonitorAspect {
   @Around("annotation(Monitor) && ???)
   public void actionOnGet(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) {
      // do stuff related to get
   }

   @Around("annotation(Monitor) && ???)
   public void actionOnSet(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) {
      // do stuff related to set
   }
}
```

Is that possible?
Thanks for any info.

Comment: Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very specific. For example, do you wish to intercept

1. any read/write field access (from inside getters or elsewhere in the code),
2. getter/setter execution in general,
3. read/write field access, but only directly from within getter/setter methods,
4. read/write field access from within getter/setter methods including (helper) methods called by getters/setters,
5. something else?

I am going to assume option 1.

I also have no idea what

```java
// do stuff related to get
```

is supposed to mean. What exactly that "stuff" is, determines what kind of advice (before, after, around) you should use and how to implement that advice. Henceforth, I am going to assume you simply want to log that the field read/write access happened, not logging any field values as such. If you need anything more sophisticated, I have no idea, because you just call it "stuff".

So here is a simple [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```java
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Monitor { }
```

```java
public class Point {
  @Monitor
  private int x;

  public int getX() { return x; }
  public void setX(int v) { x = v; }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Point p = new Point();
    // Indirect read/write access using setter/getter
    p.setX(11);
    System.out.println(p.getX());

    // Direct read/write access
    p.x = 22;
    System.out.println(p.x);
  }
}
```

```java
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint.EnclosingStaticPart;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
class MonitorAspect {
  @Around("get(@Monitor * *)")
  public Object actionOnGet(ProceedingJoinPoint jp, EnclosingStaticPart enclosingStaticPart) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(jp + ", enclosed by " + enclosingStaticPart);
    return jp.proceed();
  }

  @Around("set(@Monitor * *)")
  public Object actionOnSet(ProceedingJoinPoint jp, EnclosingStaticPart enclosingStaticPart) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(jp + ", enclosed by " + enclosingStaticPart);
    return jp.proceed();
  }
}
```

When running the program, the console log says:

```
set(int Point.x), enclosed by execution(void Point.setX(int))
get(int Point.x), enclosed by execution(int Point.getX())
11
set(int Point.x), enclosed by execution(void Point.main(String[]))
get(int Point.x), enclosed by execution(void Point.main(String[]))
22
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Turns out I was actually interested in scenario 3 (read/write field access, but only directly from within getter/setter methods,)  Do you know how that would be different?  Also, could you recommend some reading that explains the meaning of 'set(@Monitor * *)'. Thanks.

Comment: As for recommended reading, did you try the AspectJ documentation?

Comment: Option 3 is the hardest to implement, even though it is so easy to say what you want. That would be worth an extra question, but the answer would either be complicated or make you not fully happy.